# Ubuntu Server with GNOME Desktop Envinronment - Setting Apatche configuration File Permissions

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, apache-http-server

I've installed Ubuntu Server in to a VirtualBox virtual machine. I've been able to get the GNOME desktop environment setup on it (*The default Ubuntu version*). This is an educational LAMP server, so I'm not concerned about the performance cost.

I'm trying to do some very minor reconfiguration of Apatche2 but in order to do this, I need write access to the files at `/etc/apache2/sites-available` (I think).

I'm still very new to Linux but I'm getting there. I understand that I need to change the file permissions to alter these files. (At least, according to my book). But I **have** to ask if there is a way to temporarily give myself super user access for a temporary time frame. Similar to `sudo -i`.

I'd prefer to do these changes from within the desktop environment...

If there is not a way to temporarily enable super user access (or root access), how can I change the file permissions so that I may alter the Apache configuration? My attempts at chmod is failing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a root file browser with `gksudo nautilus`.

This will allow you to either open the file as root (recommended) or change the permissions under the properties menu.

Comment: I didn't test it but this is closest to what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: It's generally a bad thing to run any graphically application (especially file browsers) with root privileges.

Comment: What's so bad about it?

Answer (score 1):

The answer was staring me in the face. In terminal, navigate to the location of the file and then run the following:

```
gksudo gedit FileToEdit
```

This will start the editor with admin privileges for that file only. This is probably one of the safer ways to accomplish what I need...

gksudo: http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/graphicalsudo

Comment: +1 since it's much better than starting whole nautilus as root.

Comment: This will work fine, but I would recommend using gksudo. It's just safer. See http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/graphicalsudo

Answer (score 0):

As you have already recognized is the `sudo` command used to execute commands with the rights of other users. The default user which `sudo` uses if you don't specify another one is the root user.

Just use `sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-available` to modify the file as root.

Comment: Good point - I didn't think of that - but this isn't a preferred solution...